# Materials tab not showing

Tags: modeling

Using Blender Version 2.91. I've purchased a model and when opening the file (and even when opening only the default cube in Blender) the materials tab isn't showing. I can't follow the tutorial to change the feet mesh. I've tried selecting the correct mesh file, I've tried old versions of Blender.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You've selected the armature, armatures don't have material

Comment: On the screenshot yes, but as I said, selecting the mesh isn't doing it. I've tried on 2.8 and it worked, but for some reason 2.91 doesn't have materials. Will I have to work on the 2.8 and miss the new features?

Comment: Maybe it's a bug, could you please share your mesh (just a part of it) so that we can try? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I'm running v2.91 and there is a material tab in Edit and Object mode. Maybe your outliner is too large and it got pushed out of sight? You can hover the mouse pointer over the tab icons and use the mouse wheel to scroll the icons.

Comment: Select the object, not the armature. Please [edit] the question  and show the interface with the selected object.